# TSL certificates for HTTPS in drogon

Tags: c++, web, server, openssl, ssl-certificate

I am currently working on a Drogon webserver project that I intend to run on my local network. I also want to use openSSL to allow for HTTPS, however, I do not understand how to create the correct certificates.

I tried to create valid certificates by using a function (`generate_key`) I got from the internet (together with my code):

```
#include <drogon/drogon.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>

bool generate_key()
{
    int             ret = 0;
    RSA             *r = NULL;
    BIGNUM                  *bne = NULL;
    BIO             *bp_public = NULL, *bp_private = NULL;

    int             bits = 4096;
    unsigned long   e = RSA_F4;

    // 1. generate rsa key
    bne = BN_new();
    ret = BN_set_word(bne,e);
    if(ret != 1){
        goto free_all;
    }

    r = RSA_new();
    ret = RSA_generate_key_ex(r, bits, bne, NULL);
    if(ret != 1){
        goto free_all;
    }

    // 2. save public key
    bp_public = BIO_new_file("public.pem", "w+");
    ret = PEM_write_bio_RSAPublicKey(bp_public, r);
    if(ret != 1){
        goto free_all;
    }

    // 3. save private key
    bp_private = BIO_new_file("private.pem", "w+");
    ret = PEM_write_bio_RSAPrivateKey(bp_private, r, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);

    // 4. free
free_all:

    BIO_free_all(bp_public);
    BIO_free_all(bp_private);
    RSA_free(r);
    BN_free(bne);

    return (ret == 1);
}

int main()
{
    generate_key();

    drogon::app().setSSLFiles("public.pem", "private.pem").addListener("0.0.0.0",8000, true);

    drogon::app().run();
    return 0;
}
```

I expected the code above to start a webserver where traffic was encrypted, however I got this error instead:

```
FATAL Reading certificate: public.pem failed. Error: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line - TcpConnectionImpl.cc:301
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::runtime_error: SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file error.
```

General info:
os: macOS 13.1

I would appreciate if someone could explain what I am doing wrong and how I should move forward to create an HTTPS web server.

All help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Seeing `goto` in important cryptographic code like this is *extremely* concerning. In C++ you have way more control here as you can trivially wrap things and have your [RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) handled properly.

Comment: PSA: In C++ prefer `nullptr` to C's typeless `NULL`.

Comment: you seem to be confused as to what that function call, `setSSLFiles` *expects*. The first argument is the path to the **certificate** of the hosted site. The second argument is the path to the *private key* related to that certificate's public key. All you're doing is generating a key pair, then sending the public key as the first argument, and private key as the second. Basically, you're guessing. You need to generate a key pair, then a proper X.509 certificate with that key pair and a proper signing authority, then provide that certificate and it's related private key.